# Ubuntu 12.04 desktop loads pretty slow after password entry

Tags: boot

Well, I have an Ubuntu 12.04 running on a Core i7 laptop, with an SSD disk. The laptop is a dual-boot. I experience a very large delay between the password entry and the Desktop showing up. In general, the process looks like this:

- Grub loads fast.
- I choose Ubuntu from the list.
- Password prompt loads fast.
- I enter the password for my user.  The computer kinda hangs. The Wifi is flashing, but the hard drive light is not flashing a lot. This takes about 30-40 seconds.
- The Desktop loads in a flash

I've experienced this issue in the past, with my standard HDD. Then I removed UbuntuOne as advised in a thread that I've seen. This seems to have helped for a while. Then I migrated to the SSD. The computer loaded pretty fast for a while, then this started happening. I don't think that it is related to the SSD, though.

I'm adding a link to a bootchart image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oyXf.png

=======================

While I was troubleshooting this, I noticed that my username shows up as **[Invalid UTF-8]** in the top right corner of the screen. These are the cases when the Desktop loads with a delay.

Sometimes, the desktop manages to load fast. In this case the username is shown normally.

The **[Invalid UTF-8]** seems to be a known bug, but I was not able to find a working solution.

Thank you for your time.

=============================

I ended up completely reinstalling the OS. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here is  a Blog by "George Georgovassilis" that has some more insight into reading the boot chart and how to speed things up...

Measuring progress

Bootchart is a nice package that protocols meticulously the entire boot process and creates graphical charts of the times and where they are spent. So the first step is getting bootchart:

```
sudo apt-get install bootchart
```

After rebooting, you can get aforementioned chart in `/var/log/bootchart`. A word of caution: the first chart is non-representative, as ureadahead is in profiling mode and slows things down. After another reboot the chart would look much better. And that is how it looks like:

[image]

The chart shows three milestones: the X-Window manager starts at 19 seconds after boot, Gnome at 41seconds and the desktop is visible at 59 seconds, which I'll consider also the entire time of the boot. That's the time to beat.

Parallelizing Ureadahead

Ureadahead takes about 10 seconds to finish filling the cache, during that time nothing else loads. This makes sense for a regular, rotational harddisk as the frequent head movements induced by processes  booting in parallel would slow things down. But since this installation is booting from an SD card, it might be worth exploring a way to run ureadahead in parallel. My first take was to put ureadahead in a script and launch it in the background:

```
/etc/init.d/bootopts

#!/bin/sh
(/sbin/ureadahead --daemon)&
```

and change `/etc/init/ureadahead.conf` to call this script instead of `/sbin/ureadahead`

The reboot is 3 seconds faster which are gained somewhere between booting X and booting Gnome. Disappointingly, the new chart shows that ureadahead is still running sequentially stalling everything after it. Some investigation shows that the I/O scheduler thinks that the SD card is a rotational device, so I'm changing the bootopts script to correct that by adding:

```
echo 0 > /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4/2-1.4:1.0/host6/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0/block/sdb/queue/rotational
```

Note that the SD card is `/dev/sdb`

After rebooting, the chart looks like this:

[image]

Much better, ureadahead runs now in parallel. Unfortunately it made the boot process 1 sec slower, mainly delaying X and Gnome. But I feel I am on to something,  so let's not just give up.

## Tweaking flashcard readahead

Some bechmarks with a simple hdparm -t -T on the flash card shows that a sequential read times with 14 MB/sec, thus 2 MB/sec short of it's nominal classification. The reason seems to be a read-ahead setting of 256,  reducing it to 128 gets the maximum of 16 MB/sec. Thus another addition to my bootopts script:

```
hdparm -a128 /dev/sdb
```

## Correcting the I/O scheduler

Another reboot later, I'm back to 56sec. I suspect that the I/O scheduler gives ureadahead the same priority as to other processes, which it really shouldn't so it should be hidden behind an ionice, thus a I modify bootopts:

```
(/usr/bin/ionice -c 3 /sbin/ureadahead --daemon)&
```

This improves boot time by another 2 sec.  The chart reveals that the flash card is still not utilised fully, so I follow these instructions  to disable journaling on the boot partition and I also disable plymouthd which is the animated bootscreen. And that does the trick, time is now down to 45 sec:

[image]

[update 2011.05.22]
I also made an experiment in the opposite direction, namely starting ionice with -c 1 which corresponds to realtime I/O which reduced startup time by another second. While at first this seems counterintuitive since fewer processes can run in parallel, at a second glance it makes sense because parallel I/O introduces some overhead.

## Deferring services

Now let's defer services not needed for the boot process to after login. My candidates:

```
mysqld
nmbd
smbd
cupsd
modem-manager
bluetoothd
alsa-store [update 2011.05.22]
alsa-restore [update 2011.05.22]
pulseaudio [update 2011.05.22]
rsync [update 2011.05.22]
apparmor - I apt-get removed that one [update 2011.05.22]
plymouthd [update 2011.05.22] I deleted the /etc/init/plymouthd*.conf files - arguably this will affect logging and the ability of services to interact with the user in case something goes wrong. Use at your own risk
ufw (firewall, there is a small security risk when setting up later) [update 2011.05.22]
acpi-support
```

All of these have upstart jobs and can be deferred by changing the start event in the respective `/etc/init/xyz.conf` files to something like "stuff-that-can-wait". 
apport [update 2011.07.07]

A new script in `/etc/init.d/stuff-that-can-wait` can then execute these  scripts. Mine looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

/etc/init.d/mysql $1
/etc/init.d/samba $1
/etc/init.d/acpi-support $1
```

And of course not to forget:

```
chmod a+x /etc/init.d/stuff-that-can-wait
```

I added it as an upstart script but it is probably easier to just add it as a startup script to the gnome session ("Startup Applications")

I then removed similar services from `/etc/rcX.d` with this command:

```
update-rc.d -f servicename remove
```

and set them up instead as upstart scripts (`stuff-that-can-wait`)

## Running init scripts in parallel

Nice post here [update 2011.05.22]
The essence is to modify `/etc/init.d/rc` to

```
CONCURRENCY=shell
```

## Taming laptop mode tools [update 2011.05.22]

There is more to do: near the end of the boot sequence, bootchart shows a long waiting mount (12 seconds) which I located in /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/journal-commit. I am modifying this file as such:

```
#!/bin/sh
exit0
```

(I probably could just have deleted it)

This one not only slashed a whopping 10 seconds off the bootchart but also the Unity Desktop built up noticeably faster.

There is also `pulseaudio` starting much earlier than it should (see Deferring Services)

## Blacklisting modules [update 2011.07.07]

This step eliminates unnecessary (for my setup) modules. Edit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf and append the lines

```
blacklist rt2800pci
blacklist rt2x00pci
blacklist parport_pc
blacklist vboxnetado
blacklist vboxnetflt
blacklist bvoxdrv
blacklist joydev
blacklist lp
blacklist hp_accel
```

and comment the `lp module` in `/etc/modules`

Which leaves us with 28sec boot time:

[image]

Copied and Edited from here → http://georgovassilis.blogspot.com/2011/05/speeding-up-ubuntu-1104-boot-time.html

I hope this helps... Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The clean-up had to be done. It saved a lot of disk space, but it could not solve the issue. The delay is still present.

Comment: Well, you seem to be booting for 64 seconds. Mine takes 56s. This is not quite different. The thing is that I'm booting from an SSD. Initially, when this problem was not present, the system would boot in 20-30 seconds. Now it is just hanging after the password entry for about 30-40 seconds before it actually shows the Desktop

Comment: @EliasP I misread the charts, my bad...